# A function of type $[0,1] \to [0,1]$

Tags: functions

I need suggestions on a continuous function with domain $[0,1]$ and range $[0,1]$ which shows **large variation in output on minor variation in the input and small variation in output on large variation in the input**. I know the function will be some variation of **exp** or **log** functions but I need some suggestions.

The definition of small variation: 0.001 and 0.002
The definition of large variation: 0.001 and 0.100

Comment: I don't know it, just guesswork. Wont $\sin(2n\pi t)$ do the job for very large n?

Comment: So, $|f(0.5) - f(0.51)| > 0.5$ and $|f(0.5) - f(0.9)| < 0.1$? But then, if $f(0.9)$ is far from $f(0.91)$, so will $f(0.5)$. The concepts of "large" and "small" need some formalizing, I suppose.

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė Edited a bit.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, since in order for large variations on input lead to small variations of input and the function to be continuous you would need some sort of symmetry or *bump* but then around the center of the bump you would have small variations lead to small variations...

Comment: @DanZimm Okay, if we forget the second part i.e. large variation leading to small variation thing.

Comment: @AbdulFatir, the problem persists. You want $f(0.1)$ close to $f(0.9)$ as well as to $f(0.91)$. However, $f(0.9)$ is far from $f(0.91)$, so what can $f(0.1)$ be?

Comment: I tried abs$(\cos(20t^8))$: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+abs%28cos%2820t%5E8%29%29+%28t+from+0+to+1%29 Give me a feedback...and you can edit coefficient and powers to fix it as you prefer...

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė Forget the second part of the question. [0,1] -> [0,1] with large variation on small variation in input.

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė if we forget large variation leading to small variation then we don't necessarily want $f(0.1)$ to be close to $f(0.9)$

Comment: @AbdulFatir, by definition continuous function is one which translates small changes in argument to small changes in value. Of course, the changes of $\sin(1/x)$ may not seem so small, but that is a matter of definition.

Comment: @MattAllegro Post it as an answer so that I can atleast upvote it. :P

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė I just realized that I didn't require continuity that much in my application. How stupid of me! sin(1/x) seriously man! Post |sin(1/x)| as an answer so that I can accept it. :|

Comment: @AbdulFatir, what exactly is your application? I wonder if what you really need isn't $sin^2(\frac x {\text{large number}})$ or event a function defined to be $1$ for, say, numbers $p/2q$ where $p, q$ are integers, and $0$ elsewhere.

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė I needed a function to map colors while rendering Iterated function systems as fractals. I got the answer by the way. :) Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One such function $[0,1]\to[0,1]$ may be
$$f(t)=\text{abs}(cos(20 t^8))$$
or
$$g(t)=1-\text{abs}(cos(20 t^8)).$$
You could do more test plots (e.g. on [WolphramAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+abs%28cos%2820t%5E8%29%29+%28t+from+0+to+1%29)) to fix it as you like: you can change the coefficient ($20$), the exponent ($8$) or the whole polynomial.

One such function
$$f(t)=\text{abs}(cos(p(t)))$$
($p(t)$ polynomial) has much larger total variation $|\Delta f|$ for $t$ close to $1$ than $t^n$.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest is $x^n$ for $n$ large.  It stays close to zero for a large range of $x$, then jumps up to $1$ at the end.  If you want the peak in the middle, you can use $\frac 1{k(x-1/2)^n+1}$ for large $n,k$.  It will be very sharply peaked around $1/2$